# VBA to flatten a file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for vba code to clean up excel files with grouped data.

With many clients, many different accounts, many different details.

100's of files, needs to be done as needed for creating reporting.

I have data that looks like this:

```
#client A#
##Account number | Account Type#
##many rows of details##
###Ticker | Quantity | Value#
###many rows of details###
```

I need this:

## client | account number | Account Type | Ticker | Quantity | Value

I have some code that almost works but have read that it's not best practice, so rather than try to figure out how to make it work thought I'd ask for help.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub crk()

Dim inv As Long, name As Long, tipe As Long
Dim assname As Long, ticker As Long, broad As Long
Dim assid As Long, value As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, clname As Long

inv = 2
name = 2
acno = 2
tipe = 2
assname = 2
ticker = 2
broad = 2
assid = 2
value = 2
clname = 2


For i = 1 To 50

    For j = 1 To 9
        Sheets("by-investor-raw").Select
        x = Cells(i, j).value
        If x = "Acct Name" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(name, 2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            name = name + 1
            
        ElseIf x = "Acct No" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(acno, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            acno = acno + 1
            
        ElseIf x = "Acct Type" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(tipe, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            tipe = tipe + 1

        ElseIf x = "Asset Name" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(assname, 5).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            assname = assname + 1

        ElseIf x = "Ticker" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(ticker, 6).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ticker = ticker + 1

        ElseIf x = "Broad" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(broad, 7).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            broad = broad + 1

        ElseIf x = "Asset ID" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(assid, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            assid = assid + 1

        ElseIf x = "Value" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(value, 9).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            value = value + 1
            
        ElseIf x = "Investor" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(assid, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        ElseIf x = "Investor's Name" Then
            Cells(i + 1, j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
            Cells(clname, 10).Select
            TargetSheet.Paste
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            clname = clname + 1
            
        End If
Next j
Next i
Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
End Sub
```

This code is throwing a Runtime 1004 error at Cells(clname, 10).Select

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi Carolyn, looks like a good start, just some advice that I got here 6 months ago and it was the best advice I ever got, never use select in code, never. There is absolutely no reason.

Comment: I dont understand ... if i take the select off, it won't work?

Comment: Usually, you can do everything you are doing without select, just remove select and add it to selection, for instance, cells(i + 1, j) select selection.copy becomes cells(i+ 1,j).copy

Comment: great .. one thing that's not working is that it's skipping all the details - so it is pulling the first & second level correctly but the details are not getting copied over; it's skipping to the next 2nd level. hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this, also the variable acno was not defined, as well as x.

```
Option Explicit

Sub crk()

Dim inv As Long, name As Long, tipe As Long
Dim assname As Long, ticker As Long, broad As Long
Dim assid As Long, value As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, clname As Long
Dim acno, x


inv = 2
name = 2
acno = 2
tipe = 2
assname = 2
ticker = 2
broad = 2
assid = 2
value = 2
clname = 2


For i = 1 To 50

    For j = 1 To 9
        x = Cells(i, j).value
        If x = "Acct Name" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(name, 2)
            name = name + 1
        ElseIf x = "Acct No" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(acno, 3)
            acno = acno + 1

        ElseIf x = "Acct Type" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(tipe, 4)
            tipe = tipe + 1

        ElseIf x = "Asset Name" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(assname, 5)
            assname = assname + 1

        ElseIf x = "Ticker" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(ticker, 6)
            ticker = ticker + 1

        ElseIf x = "Broad" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(broad, 7)
            broad = broad + 1

        ElseIf x = "Asset ID" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(assid, 8)
            assid = assid + 1

        ElseIf x = "Value" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(value, 9)
            value = value + 1

        ElseIf x = "Investor" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(assid, 1)

        ElseIf x = "Investor's Name" Then
            Sheets("by-investor-raw").Cells(i + 1, j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("portfolio-clean").Cells(clname, 10)
            clname = clname + 1

        End If
Next j
Next i
Sheets("portfolio-clean").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, ElseIf x = "Investor" Then does not increment at the end of the if statement.